# Notification Number and Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number

Can anyone please confirm if this was removed from ICS (or before)? I usually do my testing in 2.2 and just noticed the little number badge isnt showing in ice cream sandwich in the status bar. Which version was it removed or is this just a bug?

Comment: What do you mean "removed" - Which types of notifications were you seeing it for on 2.2 that you aren't now?

Comment: which types? what do you mean? Ones I make.... Notification.number = x

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the general built-in notifications for things like mail, sms, etc.  My mistake!

Comment: it's still in 2.3.3... but its missing from honeycomb and ics... x_X

Comment: From the docs: "The system may or may not use this field to modify the appearance of the notification."  Sadface.  I liked the feature.  No idea what they think they're gaining by making it inconsistent between different phones/versions.  ICS didn't seem to deprecate it; it just doesn't do anything now.  Now I have to go make a bunch of green bubble icons to achieve the same effect.  :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the number badge is no longer overlaid on the notification icon in Android 3.0 and later.