# Android: In 4.0.3 Notification.Builder is Not Found

Tags: android

I am getting Class Not Found exception in 4.0.3 on doing below..

`Class<?> notifyBuilder = null;
        try {
            notifyBuilder = Class.forName("android.app.Notification.Builder");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Plz Help..

Comment: this may help u http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: shouldn't be `android.app.Notification$Builder` since `Notification` is class and `Builder` is inner class of it?

Comment: @Selvin It Worked with Notification$Builder thanks..But it works well for android.app.AlertDialog.Builder Strange Right!!!???

Comment: Is there a reason why you are accessing this via reflection? Bear in mind that the Android Support package has `NotificationCompat.Builder` that you can use going back to API Level 4.

Comment: Was trying to Fix this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350615/notification-number-and-ice-cream-sandwich my app is intended to run on 2.2 onwards..

Comment: `Notification.Builder` has no impact on where the number is displayed.

Comment: @CommnsWare it does have Effect in ICS, Number will Displayed once u drag N Tray!!!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download the compatibility library for phones that are older than 3.0. You can find more information about that here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Also, here is a link that will help with how to implement the notifications using the "NotificationCompat.Builder" (note the postfix Compat):

[How exactly to use Notification.Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391870/how-exactly-to-use-notification-builder)

Answer (score 0):

Using this Worked "android.app.Notification$Builder"

Answer (score 0):

this worked for my 4.0.3 android app [web tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)